# Integrating Flutter with Workday and potential use of Firebase for Web and Mobile Applications

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, single-sign-on, workday-api

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm currently working on a project where I need to integrate Flutter with Workday, a cloud-based human resources management system. I've been researching on how to achieve this integration, but I haven't been able to find any comprehensive resources or examples.

Specifically, I would like to know:

Are there any existing libraries, packages, or SDKs available that facilitate the integration between Flutter and Workday? If so, what are they and how can I use them?

Is it possible to utilize Firebase as part of this integration for both web and mobile applications? Can Firebase Authentication be used to handle user login and session management, alongside Workday, in a unified manner across different platforms?

Are there any best practices or recommended approaches for integrating Flutter with Workday? I'm particularly interested in handling user authentication and synchronization of user data between the two platforms.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, code examples, or reference materials that could help me achieve this integration successfully.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.